Изменить IconButton с отключенного положения в AppBar
как изменить IconButton с отключенного положения при изменении текста?
Пришел к такому варианту не знаю насколько правильно так делать, но больше ничего не могу придумать.
В гугле ничего не получилось найти подобного.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyScreen> createState() => _MyScreenState();
}

class _MyScreenState extends State<MyScreen> {
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller.addListener(setListener);
  }

  void setListener() {
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.removeListener(setListener);
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('MyScreen'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            onPressed: _controller.text != ''
                ? () {
                    ///какой то код
                  }
                : null,
            icon: Icon(Icons.abc),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body:

          ///...
          TextFormField(
        controller: _controller,
      ),

      ///....
    );
  }
}

